# Как организовать взаимодействие XAMP с Python?

Tags: python, php, xampp

Из веб-страницы локального сервера (развернут XAMP) происходит вызов функции PHP, откуда в свою очередь вызывается python-скрипт.

```
$result = system('/home/user/main.py'); // пробовал exec, shell_exec
file_put_contents(DIR_LOGS ."/Log2",print_r($result,true));
```

В main.py исправил пути на абсолютные, тем самым убрав часть ошибок.

```
def start(abspath):
  main_test_file = abspath + globval.getStrGlobValue('files','test_list') 
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  tree = ET.parse(main_test_file)
  print(main_test_file)
```

получал ошибку **undefined symbol: XML_Set Hash Salt**. Комментируя строку 'tree=...' получал название файла. Запуск команды

```
$result = system('whoami');
```

определил что пользователь не www-data, а daemon. Создал группу, добавил в нее пользователя daemon, дал права на папку с python скриптами. Вместо ошибки стал получать `[H[J` ( ESC[HESC[J )
Когда происходит консольный запуск от пользователя user с рутовыми правами - все работает корректно. Куда копать ?

Comment: частичное решение, у меня веб-сервер в локальной сети, убрал ввод пароля от пользователя daemon и запускаю python-скрипт от имени daemon. `$result = exec('sudo -u daemon /home/user/main.py');`  [Источник] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811253/execute-python-script-from-php)